# Why sending file to watchOS2 simulator from iPhone simulator won't work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, watchos-2

I am trying to copy database from iOS 9 iPhone to watchOS 2 Apple Watch (Both simulators) and, nothing. File/files is/are no where to found. (searched everywhere)

I want to transfer database when entering in the application from iPhone to Apple Watch even if only application on iPhone is on(app on watchOS2 is off).
What am i doing wrong?

```
+(BOOL)initDatabase{
    BOOL ok = NO;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *err;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
    ok = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (!ok){
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
        ok = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&err];
        if (!ok) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database. Error: '%@'.", [err localizedDescription]);
        }

    }
    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
        WCSession* session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];
        NSLog(@"watch url: %@",session.watchDirectoryURL);
        //            session.watchDirectoryURL;
    }


    [[WCSession defaultSession] transferFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:writableDBPath] metadata:nil];

    [[Config sharedInstance] addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:writableDBPath]];

    ok = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (ok){


        databasePath = writableDBPath;
        database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];
        [database open];
        NSLog(@"database path: %@",databasePath);




    }
        return ok;
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented the sending side confirmation delegate for file transfers:
[- session:didFinishFileTransfer:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSessionDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WCSessionDelegate/session:didFinishFileTransfer:error:)
?

If so, any errors being returned?

Comment: yes, i can't look now but from what I remember no error was returned

Comment: Cool. I'd suggest filing a bug report as it sounds like you are hitting some sort of bug. Great if you could report back here with the radar number so that any perusing apple engineers can easily find it!