# How can i check from watchOS 2 if application on iPhone is opened or not and be able to send NSUserDefaults no matter the app status?

Tags: ios, watchkit, ios9, watchos-2

How can I check from **watchOS 2** if application on **iPhone** is opened or not?

I want to send a message with `NSUserDefaults` from watch to iPhone via `sendMessage` (to be able to update interface on phone when message received) when both applications are running and I want to send `NSUserDefaults` even if only **watchOS 2** app is running.

From what I read I found this:

```
/** The counterpart app must be reachable for a send message to succeed. */
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=isReachable) BOOL reachable;
```

It's always reachable from what I check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reachable means the apple watch and iPhone are connected via bluetooth or wifi. It doesn't necessarily mean the iPhone app is running. If reachable is true, when you try to sendMessage from the apple watch it will launch the iPhone app in the background. You need to assign the WKSession delegate as soon as possible because the delegates methods (sendMessage) will fire soon. I think what you are saying you want to do is call sendMessage if you can, and it not use the transferUserInfo method instead. To do this, first on your apple watch:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
    session.delegate = self
    session.activateSession()

    // NOTE: This should be your custom message dictionary
    // You don't necessarily call the following code in
    // applicationDidFinishLaunching, but it is here for
    // the simplicity of the example. Call this when you want to send a message.
    let message = [String:AnyObject]()

    // To send your message.
    // You could check reachable here, but it could change between reading the
    // value and sending the message. Instead just try to send the data and if it
    // fails queue it to be sent when the connection is re-established.
    session.sendMessage(message, replyHandler: { (response) -> Void in
        // iOS app got the message successfully
    }, errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
        // iOS app failed to get message. Send it in the background
        session.transferUserInfo(message)
    })
}
```

Then, in your iOS app:

```
// Do this here so it is setup as early as possible so
// we don't miss any delegate method calls
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.watchKitSetup()  
    return true
}

func watchKitSetup() {
    // Stop if watch connectivity is not supported (such as on iPad)
    if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
}

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    // Handle the message from the apple watch...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // Update UI on the main thread if necessary
    }
}

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {
    // Handle the message from the apple watch...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // Update UI on the main thread if necessary
    }
}
```

Comment: @Thanks for your reply. I use Objective C but I figured out what to do. I couldn't manage to do because I was putting **didReceiveUserInfo** code inside a ViewController that would not be pushed if app will run in background. Thanks for solution!

Comment: Can you take a look on this one too?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071924/why-sending-file-to-watchos2-simulator-from-iphone-simulator-wont-work

Comment: I actually had tried to do something similar. Unfortunately, while I did get the sqlite database file to copy over, I couldn't select any data out of it from the watch simulator that hadn't been created on the watch.

Comment: I need to copy it, that is my problem. I don't use CoreData, I use FMDatabase and it works if I copy database from bundle..

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use the application context of WatchConnectivity:

have a look at WCSession.updateApplicationContext(  )

It sends the most important configuration info to the counterpart as soon as the counterpart is reachable, even if the counterpart is not reachable at the time of sending. If you call updateApplicationContext multiple times, only the latest is sent.

For much deeper info watch the WWDC 2015 session about WatchConnectivity: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=713

It describes more means to send data, but I think the application context fits best for you.

The session also details how to find out if the counterpart is reachable, but I think you don't need that for your use case.

Comment: I want to see if device is reachable because i select on watch something and it live modifies to phone if it's in that view, and if it's not it modifies the NSUserDefaults so when it enter he has updated content

Comment: What do you do later with the NSUserDefaults after you've written them?

Comment: Because the application context saves the data if it is not possible to send. And it sends if possible. All you do but in one step.

Comment: But before we discuss too much, try to find the time to watch the video :-)

Comment: I check on watch something->send data to phone->phone writes to NSUserDefaults->phone refresh interface and send callback to watch that it was changed->watch moves to step 2, and so on (4 steps in total)

Comment: In this case: just send and implement the reply handler and error handler. One of both will be called and then you know :-)

Comment: That's what i did. and if not i try to use **transferUserInfo** but can't get the delegate called when entering in application. My question was if I can see if application status can be seen from watch.